# PowerAMC and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, powerdesigner

I just wanted to know if there is any way to generate a SQLite database from Poweramc ?
At first sight, it seems not, and Google isn't helping me much on this...

Thank you for your hints ;)

Comment: For anyone trying to answer this, PowerAMC = PowerDesigner (or close enough) - see http://www.sybase.co.uk/products/modelingdevelopment/poweramc

Answer (score 2):

Since there has been no answer, I guess you'll have to prepare your own DBMS definition. I would have suggested to start by making a copy of the ANSI .xdb, but I saw [someone mentioning the use of mySQL .xdb](http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/06/11/sqlite-essentials/).

Update: I have started [a DBMS for SQLite 3](https://github.com/pascalbaryton/PDThings/tree/master/DBMS).