# how to generate sqlite database from CDM Model in PowerDesigner?

Tags: sqlite, powerdesigner

I have a Conceptual Data Model in powerdesigner and I want generate Sqlite DB from it, how to generate sqlite database from CDM Model in PowerDesigner?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462963/poweramc-and-sqlite).

Answer (score 2):

I have started [a DBMS for SQLite 3](https://github.com/pascalbaryton/PDThings/tree/master/DBMS)

Answer (score 2):

When you generate Physical Data Model, you can select, in the dropbox button for database selection, `ANSI Level 2`. It works flawlessly that way. Confirm your choice when you generate the script.

Just make sure to remove or comment the drop statements at the beginning of the resulting script and you should not have any error when running the script in a database client.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Tools->Generate Physical Data Model... command and select an appropriate database from the list (probably the ODBC or ANSI options since SQLLite isn't an out-of-the-box option.

OR, you could first create a database XEM for SQLLite, but that's a pretty advanced task.  I'd stick with the generic if possible.